# Как сделать редирект переводов на оригинал через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Подскажите, пожалуйста, у моего сайта много переводов, сделанных плагином, все они имеют вид
Для главной страницы:
site.com/ru , site.com/tk  (оригинал site.com)

внутренние страницы имеют такой вид URL:
site.com/ru/page site.com/tk/page  и тп (оригинал site.com/page)

Какой можно использовать правило что бы все переводы редиректили на оригинал?

Заранее спасибо за совет

Answer (score 0):

c помощью .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^tk/(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: дело в том что у меня очень много переводов (более 60), а страниц всего 8, может есть способ одно правило для всех переводов конкретной страницы сделать?

Comment: RewriteRule ^tk/(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L] - это правило перенаправит любую страницу которая начинается на /tk/ на аналогичную но в корень...или вам не это надо?

Comment: ну да наверное придется так и делать, а что делать с внутренними?

Comment: внутренние так же будут редиректится о этому правилу, тоесть kt/someUrl/ перекинет на /someUrl/

Comment: да, все работает, спасибо!

Comment: Если ответ вас устраивает, то отметьте его как правильный